Where does Tumble appear in Mario Party: The Top 100?
The Super Mario Wiki says that Tumble, the living dice block from Mario Party 3, makes a cameo appearance in Mario Party: The Top 100 without any explanation of where he appears.
Where does Tumble appear in Mario Party: The Top 100?

Tumble appears in the Series Guide menu (under Collection) as one of the featured characters. The list contains all of the party hosts up to the release of this game.
He does not show up in actual gameplay or minigames.

(Screenshot taken from here)
